# What's the alternative to GridAttributesTopologySpi in GridGain 6 (open source version)

Tags: grid-computing, gridgain

We're migrating an application from an older gridgain 4 codebase to gridgain 6. In the old application, we partitioned the nodes based on the grid attribute key "com.mycompany.workgroup" . The new release doesn't have a topologySpi configuration property or GridAttributesTopologySpi .

1. What is the recommended approach or alternative?
2. Do any of the supplied examples address my requirement? Maybe I missed something when browsing through them.

Thanks

```
<beans profile="default">

    <bean id="workerGrid"
          class="org.gridgain.grid.GridSpringBean">
        <property name="configuration">
            <bean parent="abstractGridConfiguration">
                <property name="gridName" value="${grid.name}-worker"/>
                <property name="userAttributes">
                    <map merge="true">
                        <entry key="com.mycompany.master" value="false"/>
                    </map>
                </property>
                <property name="topologySpi">
                    <bean class="org.gridgain.grid.spi.topology.attributes.GridAttributesTopologySpi">
                        <property name="attributes">
                            <map>
                                <entry key="com.mycompany.workgroup" value="${grid.workgroup}"/>
                            </map>
                        </property>
                    </bean>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The alternative is to use GridProjection, like so

```
Grid grid = GridGain.grid();

GridProjection prj = grid.forAttribute("com.mycompany.workgroup", "workers");

GridComputeTaskFuture<?> fut = prj.compute().execute(new MyTask());

// Synchronous wait.
prj.get();
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked .. 1). In GridGain6, is there no longer a way to configure the desired attributes via an SPI (I'm guessing not)? 2. Is there a way to specify a set of attributes at once rather than chaining them like      `GridComputeTaskFuture<GridInstanceTaskResult> future = master
                .forAttribute("com.company.master", "false")
                .forAttribute("com.mycompany.workgroup", masterInstance1.getWorkgroup())
                .compute().execute(new GridInstanceTask(), "something");` ? Thanks again

Comment: Here's another way to achieve the same result in code . Sorry about the formatting, `GridInstanceTaskResult> future = master
.forPredicate(new GridPredicate<GridNode>() {
@Override
public boolean apply(GridNode gridNode) {
 final Map<String, Object> attributes = gridNode.attributes();
 return                                 attributes.get("com.mycompany.master").equals("false") 
 &&                                         attributes.get("com.mycompany.workgroup").equals(masterInstance1.getWorkgroup());
 }
})
.compute().execute(new GridInstanceTask(), "something");
`

Comment: @VinayB 1) There is no longer a way to specify task topology through SPI 2) You can either use chaining or define your own predicate as you did.